# In Django, how to create a DB connection for every thread

Tags: python, django, database, multithreading

In my application I have a process that goes over a set of data. For each element of the set I need to run the logic to process it. I have the algorithm running sequentially just fine, but I need to improve run time execution as there are a few QuerySet operations that take time to execute.

How can I allocate a new DB connection for every thread to use? 
I have seen that I can do:

```
from django.db import connection
```

and then

```
connection.close
```

before creating my threads, but that still fails sometimes with a nasty error code from the Oracle library.
Is there a way to explicitly create a DB connection for the thread so there is no possibility of these DB errors?

Comment: Could it be this: *Since each thread maintains its own connection, your database must support at least as many simultaneous connections as you have worker threads.*

Comment: I understand that. It is not a problem. I have set 2014 connections on the Oracle back end and only 4 or 5 are used at a time by this process.

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: When the process fails I get the following on stdout:
***KPEDBG_POP_KGPPTR_TLS
Process finished with exit code 137***

I see that this is an Oracle error code, probably printed by the oracle client library, but there is not much documentation about it that I can find.

Comment: Database connections have been thread-local [since 1.4](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/db/utils.py#L64). No need to close the current connection or do anything specifically.

Comment: Thanks knbk, That actually explains things as I am using Django 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing the answer if you don't get to see the details:
**Django 1.4** started creating a new database connection for each thread. Since I am using Django 1.3.1 I don't get that behavior and hence the problem when multiple threads try to use the same DB connection.